# What is the best way to get a series of integers into a class?

Tags: c++, class, int, populate

Our assignment is to have a class which takes in integer values one at a time. With those integer values I am supposed to do a multitude of different things. Add them, take the average, find the largest and smallest value etc. I can write the functions for average and largest value and whatever but it is the very beginning that I'm struggling with.

How do I get the user inputs into my class? I have a member function and constructor. The function "next" is what I'll be using to store and pull my numbers from:

```
class Statistician{
    public:
        Statistician();

        void next (int r);
}
```

I've tried to write a for loop within the "next" function that will populate and array in order to get each value into the class but this seems to be an extremely tedious way to proceed. I'm not sure what comes next.

Should I use an array and if so how would I write the loop so that the numbers can be put in one at a time? Or is there a different way to do this? Will the class just automatically populate? (That seems unlikely)

Comment: You can initialize an array (if you want to get inputs from std I/O, use a for loop and initialize your array), and pass that array to your object's member functions.

Comment: would that array be outside of the class or would it become an object of the class> I'm still learning what a class even is and how objects work as well.

Comment: arrays are not required to do this excercise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "best" way is rather opinionated.  Some people believe the *best* way is to use a hard coded array (works really good for debugging).  Some people prefer to read numbers from a file (consistent, doesn't require a lot of typing).  Others use standard input.  There are other ways like reading from devices.

Usually to get numbers into a class, an *input* method is used.  Overloading `operator>>` is a common technique.

Here is one example:

```
struct Statistician
{
  std::vector<int> numbers;
  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Statistician& s);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Statistician& s)
{
    int n;
    while (input >> n)
    {
        s.numbers.push_back(n);
    }
    return input;
}
```

You could always input the data in another function, then pass the data to your Statistician class.

**Edit 1:  A different method**
If you are allergic to overloading operators you can declare an input function:

```
struct Statistician
{
  std::vector<int> numbers;
  void input_data(std::istream& input);
};

void Statistician::input_data(std::istream& input)
{
    int n;
    while (input >> n)
    {
        numbers.push_back(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok! So the overloading operators lecture was this last week. What is that doing? I think i know that it changes the operator ">>" but im not sure what it changes it to?

Comment: This *changes* `operator>>` so that it inputs all the data for the `Statistician` class, using an *istream*.  `std::cout` and `std::fstream` are derived from `std::istream` so you can use this with console input or from a file.  The `push_back` appends the number to the `std::vector`.

Comment: I edited my answer to include another example using an input method.  You can compare the two.  The difference is overloading `operator>>` and to support *chaining* by returning the input stream.

Comment: no i am not allergic to operator overloading. Thank you this really helped alot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Assume that it's Pseudo code of your class:

```
class Statistician {
    Statistician();
    void next(int* a);
};
```

And it's Psudo code of your main:

```
int main() {
    int arraySize = 10;
    int anArray[arraySize];
    for (int i=0; i < arraySize; ++i) {
        cin >> anArray[i];
    }
    Statistician obj;
    obj.next(anArray);
}
```

Here I'm using built-in array (C style), if you want, you can use *< array>* class.

And try to learn every thing deep in C++, because that's really important ;) (I would recommend you *Deitel C++ How To Program* )

Comment: BTW, `int anArray[arraySize]` is a VLA and not standard in the C++ language.  The preference is to use `std::vector` or dynamically allocate memory using `operator new`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thank you, yeah I mentioned that I used the "C Style" array and it's better to use `std::arary` or `std::vector` ;)

Comment: my problem here is that i wont know the array size before hand. The user will just keep inputting numbers until they are satisfied.

Comment: @Big_Nancy Then you should use `std::vector` class and maybe a Sentinel value to stop from getting new inputs!

Comment: I’ve actually scrapped the vector altogether and have gone with a simple counter. As a new number is added the counter goes up and updates the functions that depend on the numbers that are given. Because the numbers inputted do not need to be saved, the vector isnt needed. Thank you all for your help thought. It really helped me with my understanding!!!